# Filter a DataTable where the table does not contain items in List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a few problems quering a DataSet.Tables[0] and removing rows that do not meet the critira of a List.

```
//This is my list
var values = new List<string> {"Test", "Test2"};

// Now I just query the DataSet for anything that doesnt match this list
var query = from x in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            from b in values
            where !x.Field<string>("ColumnName").Contains(b)
            select x;
```

This works and returns the results but it is returning 2 x sets of the same rows (I assume because there is no join).

How can I just get Distinct values of these rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want:

```
var query = from x in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            where !values.Any(b => x.Field<string>("ColumnName").Contains(b))
            select x;
```

In other words, find all the rows where the "ColumnName" field value isn't present in any of the values in `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for are the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) or the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) methods instead of ".Contains" ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to join with your `values` list:

```
var query = from x in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        where !values.Any(str => x.Field<string>("ColumnName").Contains(str))
        select x;
```